# how to design and write code for this layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi I am a newbie to android.I need to know how to design this type of layout using xml they are using imagebuttons in bottom for all layouts

What is the bottom part called Is it Bottombar or tabbar or actionbar or Menubar.
P.S: I want to design on android 2X version. Please dont say refer to developer.android because i didn't find a satisfatory answer

Comment: please see this link http://picpaste.com/Tunewiki_tabbarbottom3-180x300-CVpaC985.png. I need to use the bottom buttons for all activities

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for designing action bars for 2.x android versions. If you want action bar at the bottom, you can use split action bar which is supported by it.